# Verifying Property of Stochastic Integral

Tags: probability-theory, inequality, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-integrals

I am trying to verify this simple property for a stochastic integral.  Given that f(t,w) is a bounded, nonanticipating function for a given Wiener process $W_t$ show that $E((\int_{0}^{T} f(s,w) dW_s)^4) \le 36T\int_{0}^{T}Ef^4(s,w)ds$ .

I know that $E((\int_{0}^{T} f(s,w) dW_s)^2)=E(\int_{0}^{T} f^2(s,w)ds)$.  I tried applying this, but I am at a loss for where the inequality and $36T$ term arrive from.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Applying Itô's formula for the Itô process

$$X_t := \int_0^t f(s) \, dW_s$$

and $f(x) := x^4$ gives

$$X_t^4 = 4 \int_0^t X_s f(s) \, dW_s + \frac{4 \cdot 3}{2} \int_0^t X_s^2 f(s)^2 \, ds.$$

Taking expecation yields

$$\begin{align*} \mathbb{E}(X_t^4) &= 6 \int_0^t \mathbb{E}(X_s^2 f(s)^2) \, ds. \end{align*}$$

Since $X_s^2$ is a submartingale, we have $\mathbb{E}(X_s^2) \leq \mathbb{E}(X_t^2)$ for all $s \leq t$. Combining this with Hölder's inequality, we find

$$\begin{align*} \mathbb{E}(X_t^4) &\leq 6 \int_0^t \sqrt{\mathbb{E}(X_s^4)} \sqrt{\mathbb{E}(|f(s)|^4)} \, ds \leq 6 \sqrt{\mathbb{E}(X_t^4)} \int_0^t \sqrt{\mathbb{E}(f(s)^4)} \, ds.\end{align*}$$

Hence,

$$\begin{align*} \mathbb{E}(|X_t|^4) \leq 36 \left[ \int_0^t \sqrt{\mathbb{E}(f(s)^4)} \, ds \right]^2. \end{align*}$$

Now the claim follows by applying Jensen's inequality.

**Remark:** The inequality is closely related to the so-called Burkholder-Davis-Gundy inequality.

Comment: Is this bound anywhere near tight? I have worked this out with a different method (I arrived at your second centered equation and then used the Ito formula a second time on $X_s^2$). Then I got a factor of $6$ instead of $36$.

Comment: @Ian No, it is not tight (I also dropped some constants in between; if I keep the constant, then I get $\approx 3,6$ instead of $36$). Why not write your method as an answer? Would be interesting.

Comment: Okay, I follow everything up until the last line.  How do we get from $$6 \mathbb{E} \left( \sup_{s \leq t} |X_s|^4 \right)^{1/2} \mathbb{E} \left( \left[\int_0^t |f(s)|^2 \, ds \right]^2 \right)^{\frac{1}{2}}$$ to $$36 \mathbb{E} \left( \left[\int_0^t |f(s)|^2 \, ds \right]^2 \right)^{\frac{1}{2}} ?$$  Also in the problem statement the coefficient in front of the expected value is $36t$.  Where does the factor of t come in?

Comment: @user75514 The line before the last one is of the form $$c \leq \sqrt{c} d$$ with $c = \mathbb{E}(\sup_{s \leq t}|X_s|^4)$. Divide both sides by $\sqrt{c}$. The $t$ comes from Jensen's inequality, as I mentioned in the last part of my proof: $$\left(\int_0^t  |g(s)| \, ds \right) \leq t \int_0^t |g(s)|^2 \, ds.$$

Comment: You're missing a $^2$ @saz.

Comment: @Ian You are right, in my last comment (last line) there is a "$^2$ missing at the left-hand side. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a different argument. Define

$$X_t = \int_0^t f(s,\omega) dW_s \\
Y_t = X_t^4 \\
Z_t = X_t^2.$$

Apply the Ito formula to $Y_t$ and $Z_t$:

$$Y_t = 4 \int_0^t f(s,\omega) X_s^3 dW_s + 6 \int_0^t f(s,\omega)^2 X_s^2 ds \\
Z_t = 2 \int_0^t f(s,\omega) X_s dW_s + \int_0^t f(s,\omega)^2 ds$$

Now substitute and take expectations, thereby canceling the stochastic integral terms. (There is a Fubini's theorem step in here which I am not writing out.)

$$\mathbb{E}(Y_t) = 6 \mathbb{E} \left ( \int_0^t f(s,\omega)^2 X_s^2 ds \right ) \\
= 6 \mathbb{E} \left ( \int_0^t \int_0^s f(s,\omega)^2 f(u,\omega)^2 du ds \right )$$

The argument of the expectation is an integral of a nonnegative function over a triangle. It only gets larger when extended to the whole square:

$$\mathbb{E}(Y_t) \leq 6 \mathbb{E} \left ( \int_0^t \int_0^t f(s,\omega)^2 f(u,\omega)^2 du ds \right ) = 6 \mathbb{E} \left ( \left ( \int_0^t f(s,\omega)^2 ds \right )^2 \right )$$

Now using Jensen's inequality and then Fubini's theorem:

$$\mathbb{E}(Y_t) \leq 6 t \mathbb{E} \left ( \int_0^t f(s,\omega)^4 ds \right ) = 6t \int_0^t \mathbb{E} \left ( f(s,\omega)^4 \right ) ds.$$

A remark: I am actually fairly sure that this allows us to change the $6$ to a $3$, because I think the integral over the triangle is exactly half the integral over the square, by a symmetry argument. We cannot do any better than $3$, as the simplest possible example $f(t,\omega) \equiv 1$ shows.

Comment: If you substitute $Z_s=X_s^2$, then you get a term of the form $$\int_0^t f(s,\omega)^2 \int_0^s f(r,\omega) X_r \, dW_r \, ds.$$ How do you know that the expectation of this term vanishes?